# How do I find the Sum and Max value per Unique ID in HIVE?

Tags: sql, hive

basically how do I turn

```
id name   quantity 
1  Jerry      1
1  Jerry      2
1  Nana       1
2  Max        4
2  Lenny      3
```

into

```
id name   quantity
1  Jerry     3
2  Max       4
```

in HIVE?
I want to sum up and find the highest quantity for each unique ID

Comment: Hi! Can you show what did you already try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use window functions with aggregation:

```
select id, name, quantity
from (select id, name, sum(quantity) as quantity,
             row_number() over (partition by id order by sum(quantity) desc) as seqnum
      from t
      group by id, name
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can first calculate the sum of quantity per group, then rank them according to descending quantity, and finally filter the rows with rank = 1.

```
select 
    id, name, quantity
from (
    select
        *,
        row_number() over (partition by id order by quantity desc) as rn 
    from (
        select id, name, sum(quantity) as quantity
        from mytable
        group by id, name
    )
) where rn = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

try like below

```
 with cte as    
(
 select id,name,sum(quantity) as q
 from table_name group by id,name
) select id,name,q from  cte t1
  where t1.q=( select max(q) from cte t2 where t1.id=t2.id)
```